# vim create new file and insert text on first line

Tags: vim

I have the following function which opens a new file in vim but I want to insert a line of text into the first line of the new file.

```
function journ(){
  datestring=`date +"%Y-%m-%d - %H%M%S - Rx2_Px -"`
  notev $datestring Journal
}
```

`notev` calls this function:

```
function notev() {
    vim "$*.md"
}
```

I want the first line of the file to read:

`# name_of_file`

Comment: What is `notev`?

Comment: @merlin2011: see amended question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `+` flag to execute arbitrary Ex commands:

```
function notev() {
    vim "$*.md" +normal\ i"# $*.md"
}
```

Comment: @romaini: that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the easiest solution is to pipe the data to the file and then start `vim`.

```
function notev() {
    echo "# $*.md" >> "$*.md"
    vim "$*.md"
}
```